# Unusure how to use curl to GET using parameters in header

Tags: curl

Following [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/securing-node-js-restful-apis-with-json-web-tokens-9f811a92bb52) example.

When I send a command to the website as thus, it works and returns a token:

```
[idf@xxxx ~]$  curl -d "name=Ivan&email=idf@xxxcom&password=secret" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST localhost:3002/api/auth/register 

{"auth":true,"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhNzIwYzZkYzI2ZjNlNzRhMjZhODg1YiIsImlhdCI6MTUxNzQyMzcyNSwiZXhwIjoxNTE3NTEwMTI1fQ.W_lffqIlGh21UD2o4Sqd6mISrAC6PKv6swTQvQV1IfU"}

[idf@xxxx ~]$
```

I am then supposed to use this token to `GET` some information about the user. I tried this:

```
[idf@xxx ~]$  curl -v -d "x-access-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhNzIwODlhNGZkZTViNzM5N2M1YjQ5YiIsImlhdCI6MTUxNzQyMjc0NiwiZXhwIjoxNTE3NTA5MTQ2fQ.7a5KPDvB-13KYrAfkBa_2-d3XKru1J1OkxWlofnxhFw" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X GET localhost:3002/api/auth/me
* About to connect() to localhost port 3002 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3002 (#0)
> GET /api/auth/me HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: localhost:3002
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 186
> 
* upload completely sent off: 186 out of 186 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 45
< ETag: W/"2d-vj/ohbytTg+R1uXxU34fCnv4o0o"
< Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 18:29:45 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[idf@xxxx ~]$
```

But it comes back with:

```
{"auth":false,"message":"No token provided."}

[idf@xxxx ~]$
```

I am almost certainly using `curl` incorrectly to pass a parameter to `GET`. What is the correct way to form the `curl GET` string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP GET request arguments are passed in the URL like this:

```
http://example.com/path/file?argument=value
```

So, in your case, the Curl command line would be:

```
curl http://localhost:3002/api/auth/me?x-access-token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhNzIwODlhNGZkZTViNzM5N2M1YjQ5YiIsImlhdCI6MTUxNzQyMjc0NiwiZXhwIjoxNTE3NTA5MTQ2fQ.7a5KPDvB-13KYrAfkBa_2-d3XKru1J1OkxWlofnxhFw
```

This should work assuming that the API is really supposed to work via GET requests and query arguments.

However, the `x-access-token` argument sounds more like an HTTP header, and then you would need to use this command line:

```
curl -H "x-access-token: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjVhNzIwODlhNGZkZTViNzM5N2M1YjQ5YiIsImlhdCI6MTUxNzQyMjc0NiwiZXhwIjoxNTE3NTA5MTQ2fQ.7a5KPDvB-13KYrAfkBa_2-d3XKru1J1OkxWlofnxhFw" http://localhost:3002/api/auth/me
```

Comment: I'm curious, which one works?